# Is it a good idea to chain multiple service calls in Angular 7

Tags: node.js, angular, web-services, express, design-patterns

I am creating a basic MEAN app and while working on it, I have to call multiple services one after the another. For example, while placing an order:

```
PlaceOrder(){
   productService.CheckAvailability().subscribe(() => {
       if (available){
          customerService.GetCustomer().subscribe(() =>{
             if(newCustomer){
                   customerService.CreateCustomer().subscribe(() => {
                         orderService.CreateOrder().subscribe(() => {
                                console.log("Order placed");
                          });
                    });
              }
              else //old customer
               {
                     orderService.CreateOrder().subscribe(() => {
                              console.log("order placed");
                      });
                }
          });
       } //endif
   });
}
```

Now, I am wondering if it is a good idea and application design to chain these service calls this way Or if this design is going to impact the application speed and efficiency. The same goes with Nodejs server also. There, I have sequential db updates.

Comment: It highly depends on the client, your server, your application, and your API. We can't just provide you a do-it-all answer to that.

Comment: No. You should use `mergeMap`. https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html. Or just create an API which will handle all this logic on back end.

Comment: Instead of making multiple service calls for creating order, it's better you create a single service(node) and handle  all the things there and return response based on the availability of the product (or) customer (or) order creation (or) failure.

Comment: @ritaj rxjs operators will still make several HTTP calls.

Comment: That's why I said "handle all logic on back end" instead

Comment: No is not, in this case you can use the `filter` operator as an "if".